# Angular js: ng-class with condition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this on my view:

```
<a href ng-repeat="alphabet in gameContent.answer.toLowerCase() track by $index" ng-class="{blank: !clickedAlpha(alphabet)}" class="alpha-button-hangman-answer {{alphabet}}">{{alphabet}}</a>
```

But the thing is that gameContent.answer can be more than one word (there is space in between). Is that possible to change the {{alphabet}} to "space" if there's space? I really have no idea how to do that.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you give more detail on what kind of error you're getting, or what kind of unexpected behavior is happening?

Comment: Please provide expected html output. It's unclear what you mean by change it to "space"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by adding a filter like so:

```
angular.module('yourModule').filter('spaceFilter', [function() {
  return function(input) {
    var result = input;
    if (input == ' ') result = 'space';
    return result;
  }
}]);
```

then in your output just do

```
{{ alphabet | spacefilter }}
```